# jQuery height, each and CSS together in Chrome works improper

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, height

I have very simple code snippet which is intended to vertically center img inside li. Work's good in every browser but Chrome where browser see always the same vale as a result of calculation which is not possible.

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var $li = $("div.operators ul > li");
    var $img;
    var liHeight = $li.height();
    var imgHeight = '';
    var addPadding = '';

    $li.each(function(){
        $img = $(this).children().children("img");
        imgHeight = $img.height();

        imgHeight += 3;

        if(!isNaN(imgHeight))
        {
            addPadding = (liHeight - imgHeight) / 2;
            $img.css("padding-top", addPadding + "px")
        }
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="operators">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="logo3.gif">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="logo5.gif">
            </div>
        </li>
            <li>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="logo.gif">
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery v@1.8.0.

Comment: You have missed the last closed `</li>` element. Also, add `;` for this code at the end: `$img.css("padding-top", addPadding + "px")`

Comment: you need to wait for your images to finish loading so either do it on window.load or [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached).

Comment: @Pavlo the `;` isn't necessary there as it's followed by a `}`.

Comment: Yes. Window.load works. Look like Chrome's JS engine is too fast :)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly a `;` is always necessary. Probably in this case not, but what if in the future he will add another line of code after that?

Comment: `;` is optional. Sure, it's good practice to always add them, but it's not *necessary*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome JavaScript engine is considered as the fastest one. Probably browser is looping through li before images are fully loaded so try (as @Pete suggested):

```
 $(window).load(function(){
       ...
    });
```

This should help.

Comment: Please note, that if you add ```width``` and ```height``` attributes to ```img``` you don't need to use window.load.